# How can I create searchmask for Mindbreeze, which is limited to only one defined Datasource, or atleast via search parameters?

Tags: search, mindbreeze

We have a mindbreeze Installation, which defines 3 Datasources. And with the editor I created a searchmask.

[image]

The generated/exported ***code*** seems to be plain **Mustache-html**,

```
<div data-template="filteredfacet" data-name="datasource/category" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-labelledby="label7841" style="position: relative;">
    <script type="text/x-mustache-template" data-tag-name="span" data-attr-title="{{name}}{{^name?}}{{html}}{{/name?}}">
            <span class="{{#showAddAnd?}}mb-add-and-available{{/showAddAnd?}}">
            {{{html}}}
            {{#showAddAnd?}} <a class="action mb-add-and"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i></a> {{/showAddAnd?}}
        </span>
        <span class="pull-right" title="{{count}}">
            {{#count?}}{{count}}{{/count?}}{{#excluded}}&ndash;{{/excluded}}
        </span>
    </script>
</div>
```

Where it only seems possible to change the look and feel.

In the [Online Documentation](http://help.mindbreeze.com/index.php?topic=doc/Documentation---Windows-eng/fabasoft-mindbreeze-enterprise-query-language-.htm) an [Cheat-Sheet](https://inspire.mindbreeze.com/de/Cheat_Sheet.html) I could find some metadata, but not the desired.

Does someone have any experience with this? Or some pointer how I can limit a search on only on specific data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a constraint for the whole search application. This also allows you to restrict to a specific data source. Just add a results display like "List", "Image Gallery" or "Map":
[image: Adding a Result List]

After adding you can change the option "Restrict the Results" to every query you want. In your case e.g. datasource/category:"Web" does the trick.
[image: "Restrict the Results" option]

Comment: Thanks for the response, it worked, and i can also change the `data-constraint` attribute with Javascript -Code so i am happy. :)